# Trying to solve for x and y unknown values in excel sheet to match random capital gain/loss amount given

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, mathematical-optimization

What formula would I need to put into columns B and D so that the capital gain or loss provided in column E makes sense? The quantity purchased must match the quantity sold. How to think about solving this problem?

[image]

Comment: When you say quantity purchased must match quantity sold, does that mean x = y? Currently you only have one equation for 2 unknowns in each row which doesn't have a single solution. Or are all x the same and all y the same across the rows?

Comment: If x = y for each row only then you can use `=E2/(-A2+C2)` for both B2 and D2 and likewise for the other rows